# How to redirect to a customized access denied page if authorization is not met?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I’m using Authorize(Roles = "HRManager,Finance")] on top of each razor pages to restrict user access. ( it works fine).
How to redirect the faild access attempt to a customized access denied page?

I developed the access denied page. But,how to call it when a user is not authianticated?

Comment: Which version of asp.net core you have used?

Comment: Asp.net core version 6.0.403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use startup ,try :

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opts =>
            {                   
                opts.AccessDeniedPath = "/xxx/xxx";
            });
```

Comment: I save the accessdenied.cshtml under /account/manage/accessdenied.cshtml. But, page can’t be found

Comment: Managed to change the cookie path, but the accessdenied.cshtml file is not recognized.

Comment: @abdulkareemamoora "he accessdenied.cshtml file is not recognized" , maybe  you need set correct route to the  the accessdenied.cshtml file.  What's your structure of `account/manage/accessdenied.cshtml` looks like ?

Comment: The issue I face it is that the vs code refused to create  the accessdenied.cshtml file in the same folder. I think the file is hidden. Therefore, I’ve created access-denied.cshtml in the same folder to avoid this issue and changed the file name in the cookie as well.